# Mongodb high page faults and high lock but enough memory?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

The machine is one  shard of my mongodb cluster. The cluster has three shards, shard1 in machine1 and shard2 in machine2, both 8G memory and 800G disk. The configdb, mongos and shard3 in machine3, specially 16G memory and 400G disk.

Now the problem is:

mongostat is normal in machine3, but in machine1 and machine2,  page faults and locked db always high.

I just list some status of machine1:
the result of top command:

```
[]$top
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.2%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.2%st
Mem:   7633792k total,  7302168k used,   331624k free,    84456k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  6209852k cached

 PID    PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 7562   20   0  200g 1.0g 702m S  0.3 14.3   4:36.50 mongod
```

Here is the mongostat:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res non-mapped faults     locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
 0      2     12      0       0      13       0   100g   201g   911m       101g     11  amazon:38.9%          0       3|0     1|0     4k     4k    14   01:45:35 
 0      0      3      0       0       7       1   100g   201g   912m       101g     28   amazon:1.2%          0       0|0     0|0     1k     3k    14   01:45:36 
 0      2     14      0       0      15       0   100g   201g   912m       101g     93   amazon:4.6%          0       0|0     0|0     7k     4k    14   01:45:37 
 0      0      0      0       0       1       0   100g   201g   911m       101g    141   amazon:0.2%          0       0|0     0|0    62b     2k    14   01:45:38 
 0      6     24      0       0      25       0   100g   201g   913m       101g    123   amazon:6.4%          0       0|0     0|0     8k     6k    14   01:45:39 
 0      1      9      0       0      10       0   100g   201g   912m       101g     33   amazon:4.2%          0       0|0     0|0     3k     3k    14   01:45:40 
 0     12     59      0       0      58       0   100g   201g   914m       101g    108  amazon:30.0%          0       1|0     0|1    24k    12k    14   01:45:41 
 0     20     93      0       0      96       0   100g   201g   911m       101g    114  amazon:36.1%          0       0|0     0|0    33k    17k    14   01:45:42 
 0     19     84      0       0      86       0   100g   201g   913m       101g    103  amazon:43.9%          0       0|0     1|0    28k    16k    14   01:45:43 
 0      9     29      0       0      26       0   100g   201g   914m       101g     37   amazon:5.5%          0       5|0     0|1    11k     6k    14   01:45:44
```

and here is the server status:

```
> db.serverStatus()
{
    "host" : "XX-XX-XX-XX:25018",
    "version" : "2.2.3",
    "process" : "mongod",
    "pid" : 7562,
    "uptime" : 1410,
    "uptimeMillis" : NumberLong(1410211),
    "uptimeEstimate" : 1390,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2013-03-22T01:49:01.459Z"),
    "locks" : {
        "." : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "R" : NumberLong(563437),
                "W" : NumberLong(22798453)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "R" : NumberLong(303677814),
                "W" : NumberLong(59991149)
            }
        },
        "admin" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {   
            }
        },
        "local" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(6613),
                "w" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1937433),
                "w" : NumberLong(0)
            }
        },
        "amazon" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(203845605),
                "w" : NumberLong(651848025)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(621538184),
                "w" : NumberLong(1525509360)
            }
        },
        "test" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(5143),
                "w" : NumberLong(999532)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(157712),
                "w" : NumberLong(60)
            }
        }
    },
    "globalLock" : {
        "totalTime" : NumberLong(1410211000),
        "lockTime" : NumberLong(22798453),
        "currentQueue" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "readers" : 0,
            "writers" : 0
        },
        "activeClients" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "readers" : 0,
            "writers" : 0
        }
    },
    "mem" : {
        "bits" : 64,
        "resident" : 945,
        "virtual" : 205577,
        "supported" : true,
        "mapped" : 102383,
        "mappedWithJournal" : 204766
    },
    "connections" : {
        "current" : 14,
        "available" : 805
    },
    "extra_info" : {
        "note" : "fields vary by platform",
        "heap_usage_bytes" : 190782680,
        "page_faults" : 68002
    },
    "indexCounters" : {
        "btree" : {
            "accesses" : 274412,
            "hits" : 274412,
            "misses" : 0,
            "resets" : 0,
            "missRatio" : 0
        }
    },
    "backgroundFlushing" : {
        "flushes" : 23,
        "total_ms" : 89781,
        "average_ms" : 3903.521739130435,
        "last_ms" : 929,
        "last_finished" : ISODate("2013-03-22T01:48:32.243Z")
    },
    "cursors" : {
        "totalOpen" : 0,
        "clientCursors_size" : 0,
        "timedOut" : 0
    },
    "network" : {
        "bytesIn" : 11325630,
        "bytesOut" : 181775584,
        "numRequests" : 67850
    },
    "opcounters" : {
        "insert" : 157,
        "query" : 6898,
        "update" : 29954,
        "delete" : 0,
        "getmore" : 0,
        "command" : 30902
    },
    "asserts" : {
        "regular" : 0,
        "warning" : 0,
        "msg" : 0,
        "user" : 1,
        "rollovers" : 0
    },
    "writeBacksQueued" : false,
    "dur" : {
        "commits" : 27,
        "journaledMB" : 0.36864,
        "writeToDataFilesMB" : 1.241313,
        "compression" : 0.2963027264769924,
        "commitsInWriteLock" : 0,
        "earlyCommits" : 0,
        "timeMs" : {
            "dt" : 3269,
            "prepLogBuffer" : 0,
            "writeToJournal" : 442,
            "writeToDataFiles" : 4,
            "remapPrivateView" : 23
        }
    },
    "recordStats" : {
        "accessesNotInMemory" : 32752,
        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 1656,
        "amazon" : {
            "accessesNotInMemory" : 32752,
            "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 1656
        },
        "local" : {
            "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
            "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
        },
        "test" : {
            "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
            "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Anyone give me some advise? Thanks very much.

Comment: Looks like the machine is out of memory.  Can you sort the top on resident memory?  The mongod only has 1GB, something else has another 6+GB.

Comment: OK, sorted by res. The behinds  are 32m|python, 29m|mongostat,  29m|mongostat, 29m|mongostat, 29m|mongostat, 25m|python, 15m|python, 6468|mongo, 5560|httpd, 5560|httpd, 5560|httpd, 5560|httpd, 5560|httpd. That's all.

Comment: How many writes per second do you have? You seem to have a relatively high update ratio. Are those updates increasing the document size considerably? From the values, I assume you use spinning disks? It may well be that the updates force the updated documents to be moved within the data files, which might lead to a high lock. In case you use a version < 2.6, setting [setting 'usePowerOf2Sizes'](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#collmod) for the collections of the database might help.

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems. The server started hanging up sometimes. I made a couple of changes in my queries hoping it will fix. Now i get these errors less frequently.

What i did:

1. Always use aggregation where possible instead of raw js
2. Make my queries smaller as possible. On my js execution scripts i made the the loops smaller and introduced pagination.
3. Use $lt instead of limit.
4. Get only the required field values on find().
5. Use indexes for keys fields i'm using to find. indexed fields are searched faster.
6. Limit the number of elements on $in queries
7. I use a php ORM to save my objects as mongo documents. Some of my documents were really big. I split certain documents in to smaller ones so they get saved quickly.

Hope these tips help.